# firing a breakpoint in Xcode 7 takes me to the thread screen

Tags: multithreading, breakpoints, xcode7

Xcode 7 firing a breakpoint takes me to the thread screen instead of pointing to the line where break point is set.
Even xcode 6 does the same after installing Xcode 7.
Did i do any changes in settings?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened Product->scheme->edit scheme. 
in Run and test check build configuration is Debug and debugger is LLDB

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Debug -> Debug Workflow -> Always Show Disassembly` un-check it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by resetting Xcode i.e
 Run command in terminal :

- defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode